# Overwrite rewrite-slug of built in post-type 'post'

Tags: url-rewriting, post-type

I need to change the rewrite-slug of the built in post-type 'post' to 'example.com/magazine/news/any-nice-news-item'.

When I re-register the post-type 'post' and set the rewrite-slug to 'magazine/news' it works fine. But now I'm not sure about any side-effects. Does anybody have any positive or negative experience with that?

Here is the code:

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
    ),
    'public'  => true,
    /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'magazine/news'),
    'query_var' => false,
    'delete_with_user' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
) );
```

Comment: What the propose of **re-register** post type post ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to re register post type.

Symply go in you backend, *Settings > Permalinks* and set the permalink structure to a custom one: `/magazine/news/%postname%/` then save changes.

See image below:

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I already tried that. But unfortunately it also changed the url-base for the single-views of **all custom post-types**.

Comment: @MatthiasLohscheidt - that is controlled by the `with_front` argument when a custom post type is registered. it should be set to `false` to not add the `post` post type's prefix.

Comment: @Milo – good to know. I'll try that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend reregistering the 'posts' post-type. Modifying _builtins can be a headache.

It may be best to simply change the "category Permalink" under Settings > Permalinks to:

'magazine/news/'

Or to create a subcategory named "news" with a parent category named "magazine", and use something like the "WP Htaccess Control" plugin to strip out the "category/" portion of the slug from posts.

Comment: Thanks Courtney! Probably you're right, it's better to leave the built-ins unmodified. The idea with the subcategory sounds interesting. But in the end I just created a new custom post-type called 'news' with a rewrite-slug of 'magazine/news'. I think that's a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The options above re-write every URL to be under that slug.  You need to hook in with the registered_post_type to adjust it "solely" for the 'post' post type.